# Cross database connection issue in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Im trying to fetch data from A table to another Database using Forigen Data Wrapper.

It works fine in my system. But the same commands are throwing errors in Remote Server.

```
CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER fwd_test VALIDATOR postgresql_fdw_validator;
CREATE SERVER ser_test FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER fwd_test OPTIONS (hostaddr '127.0.0.1', dbname 'database_one', port '5433');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER ser_test OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'emr123');
SELECT dblink_connect('ser_test');
```

And server returns the following error

> ```
> ERROR: could not establish connection
> SQL state: 08001
> Detail: missing "=" after "ser_test" in connection info string
> ```

Same set of lines is working in local instance.

Comment: dblink_connect is used to check the connection  here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Surprisingly enough, `dblink_connect()` will accept a foreign server name in place of a connection string: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html#idm46428636501792

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the docs, `dblink_connect()` was extended to accept a foreign server name in between [9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html#AEN147159) and [9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html#AEN147159).

I'm guessing (based on the question tag) that your remote server is running 9.1, but your local instance is something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

You need not create your own foreign data wrapper; the extension creates one for you that is called `postgres_fdw`.

You can of course create a new foreign data wrapper object, but the correct way to do it would be like this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER fdw_test
  HANDLER postgres_fdw_handler
  VALIDATOR postgres_fdw_validator;
```

You forgot the handler, without which the foreign data wrapper does not know where its code is.

Your PostgreSQL 9.1 tag makes no sense, since postgres_fdw was added with version 9.3.